# Trying to Knit a template

Tags: r, templates, r-markdown, knitr

After creating an rmd file, I keep getting this error on my Render while trying to knit a CV template and i have tried everything yet no breakthrough. I'm using R-stuiod cloud

! Undefined control sequence.
l.76 \NewDocumentCommand
\citeproctext{}{}

Error: LaTeX failed to compile CV-Example.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See CV-Example.log for more info.
Execution halted

I try to knit a template

Comment: Hi @ChrisOkorie, welcome to SO! It's always useful to provide the code of a minimum example that you are using in order to diagnose the issue. E.g., it would be helpful to have a minimum example of the .Rmd file you are trying to knit, the command you are using to knit, etc.

Comment: The error is coming from LaTeX--my guess is that that your template is missing `\usepackage{xparse}`, which defines the `\NewDocumentCommand` command

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same problem. I followed all the tips I could find online including reinstalling all packages, updating packages, uninstalling & reinstalling tinytex.
I even inserted the code chunk below

```
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
```

into the Curriculum Vitea template which just lead to a new error message

"! LaTeX Error: File `tikz.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *>

Error: LaTeX failed to compile CV-Example.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See CV-Example.log for more info.
Execution halted"

However, I'm using RStudio desktop so these steps might work for you. Give them a try.

The RMarkdown code is shown below

---

name: Marie

surname: Curie

position: "Professor"

address: "School of Physics & Chemistry, École Normale Supérieure"

phone: +1 22 3333 4444

pronouns: she/her

profilepic: mariecurie.jpg

www: mariecurie.com

email: "Marie.Curie@ens.fr"

twitter: mariecurie

github: mariecurie

linkedin: mariecurie

date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"

aboutme: "Marie is a Polish and naturalized-French physicist and chemist who conducts pioneering research on radioactivity."

output: vitae::twentyseconds

---

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
library(vitae)
```

## Some stuff about me

- I poisoned myself doing research.
- I was the first woman to win a Nobel prize
- I was the first person and only woman to win a Nobel prize in two different sciences.

## Education

```
library(tibble)
tribble(
  ~ Degree, ~ Year, ~ Institution, ~ Where,
  "Informal studies", "1889-91", "Flying University", "Warsaw, Poland",
  "Master of Physics", "1893", "Sorbonne Université", "Paris, France",
  "Master of Mathematics", "1894", "Sorbonne Université", "Paris, France"
) %>% 
  detailed_entries(Degree, Year, Institution, Where)
```

## Nobel Prizes

```
tribble(
  ~Year, ~Type, ~Desc,
  1903, "Physics", "Awarded for her work on radioactivity with Pierre Curie and Henri Becquerel",
  1911, "Chemistry", "Awarded for the discovery of radium and polonium"
) %>% 
  brief_entries(
    glue::glue("Nobel Prize in {Type}"),
    Year, 
    Desc
  )
```

## Publications

```
library(dplyr)
knitr::write_bib(c("vitae", "tibble"), "packages.bib")

bibliography_entries("packages.bib") %>%
  arrange(desc(author$family), issued)
```